# Does JOIN condition work like a loop on the joined table?

Tags: sql-server, join

Do `JOIN` conditions work like a loop? (like `Foreach`)
and if so, does it run the loop on the first table (the one after `SELECT`) or the second table (the one after `JOIN` clause) ?

Let's say you have the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers JOIN Orders ON Customers.ID = Orders.CustomerID
```

What I want to know is that, does this `ON` clause, check the condition for every record in the second table one by one, to see which one of them meets the condition?

Comment: You described nested loops algorithm. There are two additional: merge and hash

Comment: I'm fairly new to sql (and programming in general for that matter)

so

I did not understand what you just said

do you mean I have to read documents on nested loops algorithm?

Comment: Check out https://www.sqlshack.com/internals-of-physical-join-operators-nested-loops-join-hash-match-join-merge-join-in-sql-server/

Comment: Do you want to know internally how it does this, or do you want to know what it logically does and how the results are presented?

Comment: And there is a great series on Simple Talk from Fabiano Amorim about all the operators one can encounter in Query Execution plans -> https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/showplan-operator-of-the-week-merge-join/

Comment: Note that the SQL language is declarative, where one describes the desired results in set-based terms (JOIN, UNION, etc.) and the database engine decides the procedural aspects of how to accomplish the result efficiently. The execution plan exposes how the result is obtained. SQL differs from other programming languages, where one specifies how the operation is done in procedural terms, like looping.

Comment: @Charlieface actually I want to know both

the answers others gave helped get somewhat of a grasp on the matter, but I will have to read more stuff on the subject. do you know a reliable source?

Answer (score 0):

JOIN is mathematical operator like multiplication. To execute a multiplication there are several algorithms. The classical one that you learned in school, [but some different more interesting in computer programming to decrease the computational time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm).

In RDBMS, many algorithms are programmed inside the SQL engine to solve the basic operation of relational algebrae...

In low-end RDBMS like MySQL there was only one algorithm, and that is the nested loops (Hash join has been added in 2019). In more professional RDBMS you will find 3 algorithms: nested loops, hash and merge. In the most high-end RDBMS you will find some more algorithms (UNION or CONCATENATE join, [graphical transverse](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2206/2206.10435.pdf), ...) or refinement to those primary ones ([adaptive joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver16#adaptive)).

The reason why a RDBMS engine uses several algorithms is that each algoritms has it own performances facing some statistics, data structures and join complexity. If the join is a simple one with only the equality of two columns from two different tables, the three techniques are available... But:

- nested loops need *n* x *m* iterations
- merge loop needs at maximum *n* + *m* iteration
- hash join is a more complex algorithm, heavy in terms of computation,
  but will be faster if *n* and *m* are great

*n* and *m* are the number of rows estimated from the two tables to be joined

Comment: MySQL has actually a 2nd algorithm in latest version (Block Nested Loop Join) which is  a variation of Loop join algorithm. But MariaDB - which is a MySQL fork - has several other algorithms: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/block-based-join-algorithms/

Comment: It is some variations of nested loop and joins... No MERGE JOIN which is a classical when the database have indexes !

Comment: i can't vote you're answer cause i don't have any reputation yet, but even though it wasn't quite the answer to what i asked, but it helped a lot to get a good understanding of the matter, which is exactly what i need. tnx a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ta JOIN tb ON condition
```

gives the same results as the nested loop:

```
for each row of ta
    for each row of tb
        if condition
            append the row to the resultset
```

...but without any guarantee on the order of rows.

In fact, thinking about it as nested loops is misleading, because you will end up thinking the rows will be in a specific order (which is wrong) or not correctly optimize your join conditions.

Suppose the tables contain:

```
ta.value
----
A
C
D
E
F
Z    

tb.value
----
B
C
E
X
```

If you join them on ta.value=tb.value, and the database supports it, it could use a merge join. This involves sorting both tables (or using an index if available, which is convenient since it is already sorted), and putting them side to side (virtually) like so:

```
ta          tb
----        ----
A           
            B
C           C       <- match
D           
E           E       <- match
F
            X
Z
```

Finding matching values between sorted sets is very easy, you can do it visually. There's no need to search for the match in the whole other set.

The advantage of this method is that there is no random access. Both sets are scanned sequentially and only once, which is important if the data sets are large.

Consider the following situation:

You have a big ring binder with a thick pile of tax forms in it, which you just sorted by date, and you feel proud of yourself. Then you notice another pile of tax forms you forgot to insert.

The optimum solution is to sort the pile in the same order as the binder, then leaf through both the binder and the sorted pile of forms in order, inserting the forms into the binder in the correct spot. That's a manual merge join.

A manual nested loop join with index would be: for each new form, find where it should go in the binder, and put it in. If the pile is not sorted, you'd have to leaf through the binder in both directions a lot more, doing random access, and it will be slower.

Comment: this wasn't quite what i asked, but it explained how the system works very clearly, and helped me get a better understanding of the stuff

tnx amigo <3

just one thing i didn't quite understand. you said the nested loop isn't quite like a foreach loop, because it sorts the rows in the manner it should be, but a loop doesn't do that.

see if i got this right => the nested loop (also merge loop and hash join) is an algorithm that does two things: 1. join rows of data  2. sorts them.

?

Comment: Nested loop is like a foreach loop: "for each row of tablea, look up corresponding row(s) in tableb". That will return the rows in the same order as tablea, so it guarantees an order. But a SQL JOIN does not guarantee an order, because it can use various methods that each have a favorite order to return rows.

Comment: then how does it decide which method to use?

Comment: plus, i have only ever seen one type of ordering rows in joins. I don't get what you mean by "different methods that order rows in different ways"

Comment: To decide on a join method it looks at table statistics, how many rows it expects the join will have, what indices it can use, etc. That's the optimizer's job. If you have several joins in the same query it also has to decide on the join order for best performance, etc

Comment: nice, tnx mate <3